# steps to create a "Webpack" in angular 2 using "npm"

Tags: angular, npm, webpack, typescript-typings

I am a beginner in angular2, I could not understand the concept "Webpack bundles", can anyone guide me on how to create a webpack in angular 2 using "**npm**"

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html

Comment: You can also have a look at this: https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter if you want to speed up the process

Comment: if you are at beginner level give a try for angular CLI, you can easily understand about angular 2 and its structures

Answer (score 0):

Webpack is a module bundler. It bundles the dependencies as it finds all the imports/require in the files. You can see in angular there are loads of import statements where you have to import specific `@angular` modules like:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'; // the angulars module
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component'; // custom module
```

such imports to bundle up in a single js file is done by webpack.

[Some configuration and docs @ webpack.js.org:version 2.x.x](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use [angular-cli](https://cli.angular.io/).

This is why:

> Angular CLI is simply a command line interface that bundles some of the techniques mentioned above. Like it helps you generate code, following the best practices of the official Angular 2 StyleGuide. Under the hood it uses Webpack, to the exactly the stuff we mentioned above (minify files, bundle them, etc..). The difference is that you don’t have to know Webpack, how it works and how it has to be configured and set up. It will be done by the CLI for you, obviously within the limits of it.

See this for more information: [What is the difference between Angular CLI, Webpack, Browsersync etc?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-Angular-CLI-Webpack-Browsersync-etc)